# Defining C macros in preprocessor if statements

Tags: c-preprocessor

Below I change the value of the function that I call depending on the value of INPUT:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPUT second
#if INPUT == first
#define FUNCTOCALL(X) first(X)
#elif INPUT == second
#define FUNCTOCALL(X) second(X)
#endif

void first(int x) {
    printf("first %d\n", x);
}

void second(int x) {
    printf("second %d\n", x);
}

int main() {

    FUNCTOCALL(3);

    return 0;    
}
```

However, the output is `first 3`, even if INPUT is equal to second, as above. In fact, the first branch is always entered, regardless of the value of INPUT. I'm completely stumped by this - could someone explain what stupid mistake I'm making?

Comment: `#if INPUT == first` it doesn't work this way. You can only compare *numbers*.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I spend too much time in Python-land. Thanks!

Comment: change first and second to 1 and 2

Comment: IIRC anything that is not a number is considered to be zero in this situation

Answer (score 3):

The c preprocessor only works on integer constant expressions in its conditionals.
If you give it tokens it can't expand (such as `first` or `second` where `first` and `second` aren't macros)
it'll treat them as `0` and `0 == 0` was true last time I used math. That's why the first branch is always taken.

[6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#):

> ... After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined
>   unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers
>   (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with
>   the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a
>   token. ...

Comment: +1. The relevant [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html): "Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero". If you compile with `-Wundef`, you'll get a warning saying `second is not defined, evaluates to 0`.

Comment: @Dada. Thanks. I already managed to amend it with the relevant quote from the standard #appeals_to_authority. :)

Comment: Nice, the standard is indeed a better reference that gcc, but it takes me longer to search, so I usually make due with gcc :D

Answer (score 2):

You have no *macros* `first` and `second` defined. Be aware that the pre-processor is not aware of C or C++ function names!<sup>*</sup> In comparisons and calculations (e. g. `#if value` or `#if 2*X == Y`), macros not defined (not defined at all or undefined again) or defined without value evaluate to 0. So, as `first` and `second` are not defined, `INPUT` is defined without value, and the comparison in both `#if` expressions evaluates to `0 == 0`...

However, if you *did* define the two macros as needed, they would collide with the C function names and the pre-processor would replace these with the macro values as you just defined them, most likely resulting in invalid code (e. g. functions named `1` and `2`)...

You might try this instead:

```
#define INPUT SECOND

#define FIRST 1
#define SECOND 2

#if INPUT == FIRST
#define FUNCTOCALL(X) first(X)
#elif INPUT == SECOND
#define FUNCTOCALL(X) second(X)
#else
# error INPUT not defined
#endif
```

Note the difference in case, making the macro and the function name differ.

<sub>* To be more precise, the pre-processor is not aware of *any* C or C++ tokens, so it does not know about types like int, double, structs or classes, ... – all it knows is what you make it explicitly aware of with `#define`, everything else is just text it operates on and, if encountering some known text nodes, replacing them with whatever you defined.</sub>